# Running JavaScript Koans on GitHub

Tags: javascript, github

How do I run the JavaScript Koans on the following site?

https://github.com/mrdavidlaing/javascript-koans/tree/master/koans

I follow the instructions in the **README** doc, but it just opens up some code, and I can't do anything from there.

Can somebody please give me a quick walkthrough on how to execute those Koans?  Do I need to download some type of software?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what to do: Download and extract the zip file from the github page. Navigate to the extracted folder and double-click the KoansRunner.html file.

You'll benefit from a JavaScript editor (try Notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Then go to the koans folder, open the .js files in Notepad++ and done!

Comment: I've done what you suggested warwick-  download and extracted files.  One step further along now, but still lost :) When I open the 'KoansRunner.html' file, I'm taking to a screen on the chrome browser with a bunch of pink boxes.....what am I supposed to do there?  I don't seem to be able to do anything on that page.  And when I open the 'aboutExpects' folder on the notepad, I can see a bunch of code that I can edit now, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Right, you're almost there. So the pink boxes show the results of the changes you make to the JavaScript files. If you make the correct changes and then refresh that KoansRunner.html file, the pink boxes will turn green. For example, in the first koan (function) in the aboutExpects file,  changing the value from "false" to "true" will give you correct result which you should then (after refreshing) see.

Comment: so...I've been able to download and extract the zip files, and run the 'koansrunner.html' file, which takes opens a chrome window with the pink boxes.  After that I opened the "aboutexpects" file with notepad++, and changed the following line in the first function as you've suggested.......describe("About Expects", function() {

  // We shall contemplate truth by testing reality, via spec expectations.
  it("should expect true", function() {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy(); //This should be true
  });.  I then went to the chrome browser to 'refresh', but nothing happens.  Did I miss somehting?

Comment: finally works warwick!  I hadn't saved before refreshing.  Hey,  thanks so much for your help and patience.  I never would have figured it out by myself.  How long have you been programming?  fyi, I'm trying to learn javascript to get into Hack Reactor